# There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 28,Token in error = 2 ]

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, insert-into

This is an error that I've looked into and it's difficult to interpret it into my own code. I hope some of you could shed some light on this for me!

What does the error actually mean?

How would I change my code to work aroud the error?

```
    @{
var start = "";
var end = "" ;
if(IsPost){
    start = Request.Form ["start"];
    end = Request.Form ["end"];
        var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
        var query = db.QuerySingle ("SELECT start FROM Holidays 2 where LOWER(start) = LOWER(@0)", start);
        if (query == null) {
        db.Execute("INSERT INTO Holidays 2 (start) VALUES (@0)", start);
        }
    }    
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<h1>Holidays</h1>
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Start Date</th>
<th>End Date</th>


<!--<tr>
<td>row.ID</td>
<td>row.datestart</td>
<td>row.datend</td>
</tr>  -->  

</tr>
</table>
<form method="post">
    <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      showButtonPanel: true
    });
  });

   $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      showButtonPanel: true
    });
  });
 </script>
    <div id="new">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="holidays.asp?new=1"> 
    <table id="reqholstbl" name="reqholstbl">
    </br>
    <tr> Please ensure the Holidays you are requesting are in this calendar year only.</tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="col1">First day off:</td>
    <td id="col2">
    <input type="text" name="datestart" id="datepicker" value="@Request.Form["start"]" style="border:1px solid #999;"  />
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="col1">Last day off:</td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="datend" id="datepicker1" value="@Request.Form["end"]" style="border:1px solid #999;" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    <td id="col1">Comment:</td>
    <td><input type="text" style="border:1px solid #999;" name="comments"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="col1"></td>
    <td><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" STYLE="WIDTH:80PX;"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should have specified which DB you are using, and the line which throws the error.. Besides, I don't think Javascript and html are of any relevance here. Anyway, literal 2 in "FROM Holidays 2 where" looks suspicious

Comment: What is the name of your table? if it is Holidays 2 (with space) use brackets: [Holidays 2]

Comment: @apomene
Thanks for your advice! Managed to get it working now, however another issue I've encountered is that the my date fields are not writing to the database. So my database now has an ID for each entry, but the date fields (start and end) are both _null_ .

Anyone know a way around this? I'm having a play myself, so I'm not counting on you all entirely! 

Thanks.